# java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket reading from NoSQL

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, nosql

I am trying to read data from NoSQL and inserting data in to oracle. If i truncate oracle table and try to insert, it works fine. I am getting this below error if already data exists or if i stop in middle of read/write operation and try again from the beginning i am getting the same error.

```
xx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx SEVERE AnalyticsMigrate main Exceptionjava.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.prepareForReading(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:119)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:534)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:485)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDBC 12.2 and higher uses Java NIO Calls in blocking mode - when there are interrupts done by application. Previous JDBC releases uses stream-based I/O API calls which not affected by interrupts.

Please try to use

System.setProperty("oracle.jdbc.javaNetNio", "false");

before connecting and retry